# React Native: can't load image

Tags: ios, react-native

I write a simple iOS program to show image with React Native.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  Image
} = React;

var styles = React.StyleSheet.create({

  base: {
    height: 400,
    width: 400 
}
});

class SimpleApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Image
    style={styles.base}
    source={require('image!k')}
    //source={{uri: 'http://news.xinhuanet.com/world/2015-05/09/127782089_14311512601821n.jpg'}}
      /> 
    )
  }
}

React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
```

But I got the message from iPad screen:

```
"Failed to print error:","'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'stackString.split')"
```

When I change the code to use image url

```
//source={require('image!k')}
source={{uri: 'http://news.xinhuanet.com/world/2015-05/09/127782089_14311512601821n.jpg'}}
```

I only get a red rect border.

When I use another js file, everything works well."Hello World" can show on iPad screen.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  Text,

} = React;


class SimpleApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

        <Text>Hello World</Text>

    )
  }
}

React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
```

Comment: The network `<Image>` loader only supports `png` right now from what I can tell. `jpg` appears to be supported when loading the image statically [ref](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/72c5e5d981a21ede12dcd76de5ca22a398c8bcaf/packager/packager.js#L203)

`source={require('image!k')}` is used to load an image statically, change `k` to the name of your image stored locally, `require` will base64 your image into the app

`source={{uri: 'http://...'}}` is used to load an image off the network, you are loading a jpeg which doesn't appear to be supported yet - try loading a png instead

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are using a recent version of React Native. With React Native 0.4.4 following works:

**Local image**

```
  <Image
    style={styles.base}
    source={require('image!tabnav_settings')}
  />
```

Also make sure you added the image you want to use to your image assets:

[image: Xcode Images.xcassets]

**Remote Image**

```
  <Image
    style={styles.base}
    source={{uri: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfkfD.png'}}
  />
```

Comment: Also it's same for android. If you add your images to drawable folder, you can use them dynamically.

Comment: @the_bluescreen what about react-native 0.27.2. in that version we don't need anymore to put images into drawable. in development it is working fine but in production images is not loading? any suggestion would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2):

As @potench pointed out in the comments, loading static images with a .jpg extension doesn't currently work. But if you just rename your jpg to png everything works fine. 
See also https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/521